# Activiti BPMN: Web service invocation task

Tags: web-services, service, task, activiti, bpmn

I have created normal java service tasks with activiti BPMN. But how to do $subject?  Do we have to do a java implementation and create a wsdl from it and proceed? In such a case, does activiti support wsdls? It would be great if a sample/ article could be given on this.

Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't get what you desire. You can invoke a Java method and then use your web service invoker to make a web service call. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes GokcenG. So it seems that web service tasks are not supported OOTB in activiti yet. Was just checking if there is any other way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java Service Task and Apache CXF to build proxy-classes from your wsdl-file. Another approach is to use the webservice task, which is still experimental. For more information, take a look at this blogpost: http://www.bpm-guide.de/2010/12/09/how-to-call-a-webservice-from-bpmn/

Both approaches are also described in the Book "Activiti in Action".